# Receiving and sending email using Amazon SES

Tags: mx-record, amazon-ses, amazon-sns

I have a domain configured to send mails using Amazon SES. Both sending and receiving using normal SMTP server are working just fine. I have MX record setup as `feedback-smtp.us-west-2.amazonses.com (10)` and using mail from domain `mail.mydomain.com`. I have two e-mail addresses `'mail@mydomain.com'` and `'sales@mydomain.com'`.
I now need to enable receiving using Amazon SES to process emails coming on `'mail@mydomain.com'` through SNS. I have verified this e-mail address and created rules to process it through SNS. The receiving documentation states that  I need to setup MX record as `inbound-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` which I did. I am successfully receiving incoming notifications for `'mail@mydomain.com'` but mail receiving has stopped on `'sales@mydomain.com'`. The mails sent on this address are bouncing. 
To be specific, I need to know:
"Does enabling receiving for one e-mail address on a domain has effect on all e-mail addresses of the domain?"

Comment: Setting up MX records will point **all** email for that domain to those records, so yes, mail to `sales@example.com` will now be going to SES too.